# C# AutoMapper получить атрибуты свойства

Tags: c#, .net, атрибуты, automapper

Есть следующий код на C#, который осуществляет "склеивание" объектов используя Nuget пакет AutoMapper

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestProj
{
    public class NotMapped: Attribute
    {
        public NotMapped(){}
    }

    class TestClass
    {
        public int A{get;set;}
        public int B{get;set;}
        [NotMapped]
        public int C{get;set;}
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { 
                cfg.CreateMap<TestClass, TestClass>().ForAllMembers(options =>
                {
                    options.Condition((source, destination, memberSource, memberDest) => false);
                });
            });

            var src = new TestClass(){A=1,B=1,C=1};
            var obj = new TestClass(){A=2,B=2,C=2};
            src=Mapper.Map(src,obj);
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(src));
        }
    }
}
```

Результат его выполнения вполне предсказуем, к значениям всех свойств объекта src последовательно присваиваются соответствующие значения свойств obj.
[image: {"A":2,"B":2,"C":2}]

**Вопрос:**
Можно ли каким-нибудь образом получить список атрибутов свойств и игнорировать присваивание у тех, которые помечены как [NotMapped]?

```
{"A":2,"B":2,"C":1}
```

Comment: Ну это вроде и не должно работать. Хотите игнорить свойства, [настройте это](https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/2/Pages/4)

Answer (score 1):

Делегат из метода ForAllMembers() вызывается для каждого нового свойства для объединения. При этом параметр options хранит поле MemberInfo DestinationMember. Далее наличие аттрибута легко определяется через рефлексию.

```
using System.Reflection;

...

cfg.CreateMap<TestClass, TestClass>().ForAllMembers(options =>
{
    bool isMapped = options.DestinationMember.GetCustomAttribute<NotMapped>()==null;
    Console.WriteLine(isMapped?"Mapped":"NotMapped");
    options.Condition((source, destination, memberSource, memberDest) => !isMapped);
});
```

[image: Всё очень просто]